# Expand RegexMatch To Test Against An Entire Range Of Cells - Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup

In Google Sheets, I'm trying to essentially make an address book which I then want to use as a means of working out who is associated with each row in my data spreadsheet.

From looking around, I seemed to find that the best way to do the actual search would be to use the following formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH($C$2:C, 'Address Book'!$A$2:A), 'Address Book'!$A$2:B ))
```

So my interpretation of this formula was that it is saying that for each row of column C, if it contains ANY of the values that are in Column A of the address book sheet, then show column A AND column B from the relevant row of the address book sheet.

However, I think the issue is actually that it is only looking at one row of the address book sheet as the formula only works if both the address book record and the data record use the same row number on their respective sheets. How can I expand this formula to make sure that it checks all of the values in column A of the address book sheet?

EDIT: I realise I hadn't been clear on how the cells actually work. So for example, in column C of my data sheet, each cell would look something like the following:

```
My Video Title - Joe Bloggs - ACME Co
```

And then in column A & B of my address book sheet, I then just have the names and emails listed which I then want to check against the above

```
Joe Bloggs  joebloggs@
Jon Smith   jonsmith@
```

So then I basically want to check if Joe Bloggs or Jon Smith or any other name in the address book sheet is in each row of Column C of my data sheet and if it is then get Column A AND B of the relevant row from the address book sheet

Comment: any reason why it needs to be regexed?

Answer (score 1):

try in row 2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, Address Book'!A2:B, 2, 0)))
```

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'Address Book'!A2:A)), 'Address Book'!A2:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: No that didn't work but I realise perhaps I didn't explain the data I have well enough

Comment: So to be clear, Column C in my data spreadsheet and Column A can never be exactly the same (which is what I think your formula is detecting) as column C will always have a title in front of it. 

So the reason I was using the REGEXMATCH was just to check if any of the names from Column A is used anywhere within each cell of column C.